# Do I have to publish kernel source if I release a custom kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, source, licenses

I have a kernel for an android phone ready for release. I always have the current source code already pushed to GitHub for release builds. However, I also have an experimental folder on my server where all builds I make are inside. The source code of these newer builds is not public.

Am I allowed to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must distribute the source code you have used to compile the [GPL V2 licensed] binary that you distribute, So anyone that fetch the binary can modify and recompile the source code.

The source code and binary don't have to be exactly side-by side. The source code should be easy to fetch, uncompress..., otherwise you should document how to get it,  where to get it, how to uncompress and build it...

This only applies to each and every version of the binary that you distribute (even experimental). If your experimental binary is published and overwritten, it's probably fine to publish the source repository (like git).

See  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic

Comment: Even if it's another folder on my server, I don't link to?

Comment: @TheCrazyLex, I have clarified my answer: You have to publish the source code for the binary you distribute. Your private stuff (binary and the matching source code) can remain private. To put it another way, it's not because you have publish some binary once that you must publish all subsequent  binary and matching source code.